# Using gridfs with node rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, grid

I am trying to use gridFs storage with node rest api. I am confused on how to use these two together. I am following Brad Traversy's gridfs source code for that. Should I be using those code in my node rest's 'app.js' file or in 'product.js(Route's folder)'.

Here's the gridfs code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const app = express();


const productRoutes = require("./api/routes/products");
const userRoutes = require("./api/routes/user");


app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

// Routes which should handle requests
app.use("/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
});

module.exports = app;


// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://brad:brad@ds257838.mlab.com:57838/mongouploads';

// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render('index', { files: false });
    } else {
      files.map(file => {
        if (
          file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ||
          file.contentType === 'image/png'
        ) {
          file.isImage = true;
        } else {
          file.isImage = false;
        }
      });
      res.render('index', { files: files });
    }
  });
});

// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // res.json({ file: req.file });
  res.redirect('/');
});

// @route GET /files
// @desc  Display all files in JSON
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No files exist'
      });
    }

    // Files exist
    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc  Display single file object
app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file);
  });
});

// @route GET /image/:filename
// @desc Display Image
app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }

    // Check if image
    if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: 'Not an image'
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route DELETE /files/:id
// @desc  Delete file
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err: err });
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

and here's my product.js code in route's folder in which I want to use grid fs for file storage:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

const Product = require("../models/product");

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  Product.find()
    .select("name price _id productImage reference description quantity date category")
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        products: docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            name: doc.name,
            price: doc.price,
            productImage: doc.productImage,
            reference: doc.reference,
            description: doc.description,
            quantity: doc.quantity,
            date: doc.date,
            category: doc.category,
            _id: doc._id,
            request: {
              type: "GET",
              url: "https://booksbackend.herokuapp.com/products/" + doc._id
            }
          };
        })
      };
      //   if (docs.length >= 0) {
      res.status(200).json(response);
      //   } else {
      //       res.status(404).json({
      //           message: 'No entries found'
      //       });
      //   }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

router.post("/", upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    productImage: req.file.filename,
    reference: req.body.reference,
    description: req.body.description,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    date: req.body.date,
    category: req.body.category,
    newProduct: req.body.newProduct,
    relatedProduct: req.body.relatedProduct
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Created product successfully",
        createdProduct: {
            name: result.name,
            price: result.price,
            _id: result._id,
            request: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "https://booksbackend.herokuapp.com/products/" + result._id
            }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should have MODEL, CONTROLLERS, and ROUTES in your API-server code. You can achieve it using exports and require.

ROUTES: Should only have the routing part.

```
var Express         = require('express'),
    Router          = Express.Router(), 
    roleController = require('../controllers/role.controller');

Router.route('/addRole').all().post(roleController.addRole);

module.exports = Router;
```

CONTROLLER: SHould have the business logic.

```
var roles = require('../models/role'),
    apiHandler = require('../services/api-handler');

// Add role
exports.addRole = function (req, res) {
    var newRole = new roles(req.body);
    roles.addRole(newRole, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(apiHandler.generateErrorResponse('NO_USERS'));
        } else {
            res.send(apiHandler.generateSuccessResponse('ROLE_ADDED'));
        }
    });
};
```

MODEL: Database schema and related queries.

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
// User schema
var RoleSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    permission: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }

});

var Role = module.exports = Mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema);

module.exports.addRole = function (newRole, callback) {
    newRole.save(callback);
};
```

APP.js only server and DB setup related code should be present.

---

In your case, I would suggest you **move the gridfs code to the  product.js**.

I would strongly recommend above-mentioned architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I should be moving my gridfs code to product js and changing it as route.get('/files') instead of app.get('/files').. This will work, right?

Comment: I will try it then

Answer (score 0):

I dont' understand really what you want, but i think that first you must to read this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/ go to last in Additional Resources section. Read both part1 and part2. I hope that help you

Comment: All I want to do is use grid fs with Node rest api endpoints. So don't know how to start and from where to. All I have is the source code of both the things. I have already read that documentation.